# Joda Time TimeStamp from DateTime

Tags: java, timestamp, jodatime

I'm trying to get a TimeStamp with Joda Time with the following code:

```
    DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm");
    DateTime  myDate=null;
    myDate = dtf.parseDateTime("20/12/2015 18:00");    
    System.out.println(myDate.toDateTimeISO());
    stamp=new Timestamp(myDate.getMillis());
```

When I print the date using

```
 myDate.toDateTimeISO()
```

I get

```
2015-12-20T18:00:00.000+01:00
```

But using this piece of code

```
stamp=new Timestamp(myDate.getMillis());
```

I get the timestamp of the current time, not the date I set on myDate.

What's wrong here?

Comment: What is the current time that you get? Does it happen to be the date you set but offset by the timezone?

Comment: Thu Dec 24 12:26:51 CET 2015 . The date right now.

Comment: How are you checking the timestamp?

Comment: I think the Timestamp is from java.sql package. It printed `2015-12-20T18:00:00.000Z` for ISO and `2015-12-20 18:00:00.0` for timestamp on my machine. Don't see anything wrong with it.